# Add Tunnel to an existing SSH session once logged in

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, tunnel, sshd

I know I can add tunneling to an existing ssh connection by using the EscapeChar : ~C and then the usual -L syntax.
It works.
What I'd like to do is to make this automatic when I log in.
I cannot specify anything on the command line on the client side. So I have to do it serverside.
The client connects as : ssh user@host. That's all. 
So now I add the tunnels myself once I'm logged in. 
I'd like to automate this.
How an I launch the -L commands automatically when the ssh session starts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.ssh/config` file on the client to create a tunnel whenever you connect, using the `LocalForward` keyword. See the examples on [this page](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/).

Comment: Thanks but I cannot do that. I cannot do anything on the client. I need to do this **from the server**, once logged in.

Comment: Can you `SSH` back from the server to the client? If so you could trigger the creation of a reverse tunnel (`-R` rather than `-L`) once connected

Comment: No :(. Here is what I do now: I connect, and then use the EscapeChar to add a tunnel with the usual syntax. But I need to setup many tunnels so it takes quite some time. I thought that there must be a way to run these command when I  log in, for exemple through a basrc or profile.